# How can I reduce the bundle size in React App when only using Authenticator from Amplify UI?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I would like to use the Authenticator component from [Amplify UI](https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/?platform=react) for sign in in my React App but doing so makes my apps bundle size huge; it is currently 3Mb. I have seen the discussion on reducing bundle size for [Amplify more broadly](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/3365) which led to this [release/blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/amplify-framework-announces-new-rearchitected-ui-component-and-modular-javascript-libraries/) which I have followed. I am wondering if there is something similar I should be doing to import the Authenticator from Amplify UI in such a way that it does not import the entire ui-react library because it seems that is adding 1.8Mb to my app, most of which is coming from icons if I'm reading the chart right. I import the Authenticator as shown below:

```
import { Authenticator } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react';
import '@aws-amplify/ui-react/styles.css';
```

Here is my source map for the app:
[image]

package.json looks like this:
[image]

Comment: what does your `package.json` file look like?

Comment: added package.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prior to version 2.12.0 we had some treeshaking issues in the `@aws-amplify/ui-react` package which prevented the icons from being removed. This was fixed in version 2.12.0. See [CHANGELOG.](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-ui/blob/main/packages/react/CHANGELOG.md#minor-changes-4) It looks like you may be using 2.10.4. Can you make sure you are on the latest version?

```
npm install @aws-amplify/ui-react@latest
```

If you don't see a reduction in bundle size after upgrading the latest version that's a bug, and we would like to get it fixed. You can either respond to this issue or even better would be to [open a bug here](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-ui/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=1.bug_report.yaml).

Comment: Great, can confirm when using 2.16.1 the icons have gone away and the size is greatly reduced.

Comment: I did previously also open a discussion on github but that can be closed https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-ui/discussions/1853

Comment: Glad to hear it's working for you now!

Answer (score 1):

The Authenticator component does not import anything from its parent directories, so you could probably just extract the code from [here](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-ui/tree/main/packages/react/src/components/Authenticator) and install any dependencies that are missing.